Raise message from a class in models.py in django
I have models class for Inventory Transfers or Issues Details. In the save method, I am accessing current stock level in a different model class for WarehouseStockStatus. I wish to message to the user from models.py if transferred or issued quantity exceeds current inventory levels. I am using django admin screens only. Print method will not work. Raise Validation error doesn't work. Also Messages will not work as it works only in views and templates where you have Request object. Any suggestions on how to proceed ?
I expect to print the message to the user.

Have you tried overriding the .clean() method of your model and raise a validation error? I haven't personally tested this but it should be displayed on the admin site.

Please add your models.py and forms.py code example.

Is there any reason why this couldn't be done in a form rather than the model? Feels like it should be a ValidationError of some kind.

Clarify how you want to notify the user. Are you open to using custom admin actions or overriding admin save methods?
